Fetch data to single row from multiple rows
I have a table with these columns and data:



cid
step
cr_time




120
S02
08-JUL-24 08.35.19.000 AM


120
S03
08-JUL-24 01.35.19.000 PM


120
S04
09-JUL-24 02.35.19.000 PM


121
S02
09-JUL-24 09.35.19.000 AM


121
S03
09-JUL-24 02.35.19.000 PM


122
S02
10-JUL-24 10.35.19.000 AM


122
S03
10-JUL-24 03.35.19.000 PM



How can I fetch data such a way that only row exists for one cid and shows cr_time for step ('S02', 'S03') - like this:



cid
S02_cr_time
S03_cr_time




120
08-JUL-24 08.35.19.000 AM
08-JUL-24 01.35.19.000 PM


121
09-JUL-24 09.35.19.000 AM
09-JUL-24 02.35.19.000 PM


122
10-JUL-24 10.35.19.000 AM
10-JUL-24 03.35.19.000 PM




You can use PIVOT technique here. The pivot can be done using GROUP BY and some aggregation function (MIN in next example) with condition within:
select 
    cid,
    min(case when step = 'S02' then cr_time end) S02_time,
    min(case when step = 'S03' then cr_time end) S03_time
from t
group by cid;

Try SQL online

what is the use of min here

It is only one of options. In this particular case any aggregation function can be used. Just try it here: https://sqlize.online/s/no

I have another condition where cr_time should be only between 8:30 Am and 4:30 PM.The condition should satisfy for both steps S02,S03 then only that record should be included..I used this condition (CAST (cr_time as TIME) >= "8:30 00 AM" and CAST (cr_time as TIME) <= "4:30 00 PM" ) which is working but any one of step that satisfy this the row shouldnt be included.But it is showing as null

https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle23/22fd2bd79a6de38f592e7c225bde00a5/
I have updated  the condition and I dont need the null records here.How to acheive that @Slava Rozhnev

What Your desired result in this case? Please edit the question by add this condition and your desired result

I have asked seperately.Can you answer here if u can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78776967/sql-query-ignore-row-if-data-is-null-for-multiple-rows-on-single-condition

You can use this SQL code,
SELECT 
    cid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN step = 'S02' THEN cr_time END) AS S02_cr_time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN step = 'S03' THEN cr_time END) AS S03_cr_time
FROM 
    your_table_name
GROUP BY 
    cid;


Really? You just fixed my writing?
