SQL Query - Ignore row if data is null for multiple rows on single condition
I have a below table



cid
step
cr_time




120
S02
08-JUL-24 09.35.19.000 AM


120
S03
08-JUL-24 01.35.19.000 PM


120
S04
09-JUL-24 02.35.19.000 PM


121
S02
09-JUL-24 07.35.19.000 AM


121
S03
09-JUL-24 02.35.19.000 PM


122
S02
10-JUL-24 10.35.19.000 AM


122
S03
10-JUL-24 05.35.19.000 PM



Now I need to fetch data only if both S02 and S03 time is between 8:30 AM and 4:30PM.
I was able to achieve it partially but if any of the step doesnt satisfy the condition the row shouldnt be fetched..In my case it is coming as null.
Below is the query
select 
    cid,
    min(case when step = 'S02' then cr_time end) S02_time,
    min(case when step = 'S03' then cr_time end) S03_time
from t where
    (CAST (cr_time as TIME) >= '8:30:00 AM' and CAST (cr_time as TIME) <= '4:30:00 PM')
group by cid;

I just need response like below not the null rows



cid
S02_cr_time
S03_cr_time




120
08-JUL-24 08.35.19.000 AM
08-JUL-24 01.35.19.000 PM



Query tester Link : https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle23/22fd2bd79a6de38f592e7c225bde00a5/

Try to add HAVING clause like below:
select 
    cid,
    min(case when step = 'S02' then cr_time end) S02_time,
    min(case when step = 'S03' then cr_time end) S03_time
from t where
    (CAST (cr_time as TIME) >= '8:30:00 AM' and CAST (cr_time as TIME) <= '4:30:00 PM')
group by cid
HAVING S02_time IS NOT NULL AND S03_time IS NOT NULL;


Getting ORA-00904 error -"S02_time ":invalid identifier @Sebastian

https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle21/876e7de5c5882ba2f6b26aeb02ec30aa/

Seems like you've selected "Oracle Database 21c" as your runtime.
Change that to "Oracle Database 23c Free" and then try.

Yes in my work env it is giving the same error..WHy it wont work in oracle 21?Any alternative approach for this?

https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle23/737e4f4d8cff8fea4b988d8d54d5395b/

Any alternative approach?

Alternate approach would be using CTE ( Common Table Expression ) like below:
with cte as(
    select 
        cid,
        min(case when step = 'S02' then cr_time end) S02_time,
        min(case when step = 'S03' then cr_time end) S03_time
    from t where
        (CAST (cr_time as TIME) >= '8:30:00 AM' and CAST (cr_time as TIME) <= '4:30:00 PM')
    group by cid
)
select * from cte where S02_time IS NOT NULL AND S03_time IS NOT NULL
;

sqlize.online

It is working .is there anyway to get difference between those two times in new column?

You can use HAVING to filter after the aggregation and can subtract the values to find the difference in the times:
SELECT cid,
       MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S02' THEN cr_time END) S02_time,
       MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S03' THEN cr_time END) S03_time,
       MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S03' THEN cr_time END)
         - MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S02' THEN cr_time END) AS diff
FROM   t
WHERE  CAST(cr_time AS TIME) BETWEEN TIME '08:30:00' AND TIME '16:30:00'
GROUP BY cid
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S02' THEN cr_time END) IS NOT NULL
AND    MIN(CASE WHEN step = 'S03' THEN cr_time END) IS NOT NULL;

Note: Before Oracle 23, you cannot use the aliases defined in the SELECT clause in the HAVING clause.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE t (
  cid     INT,
  step    CHAR(3),
  cr_time TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO t (cid, step, cr_time) 
SELECT 120, 'S02',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-08 09:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 'S03',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-08 13:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 'S04',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-09 14:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 'S02',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-09 07:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 'S03',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-09 14:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 'S02',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-10 10:35:19.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 'S03',  TIMESTAMP '2024-07-10 17:35:19.000' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



CID
S02_TIME
S03_TIME
DIFF




120
2024-07-08 09:35:19.000000
2024-07-08 13:35:19.000000
+000000000 04:00:00.000000



fiddle
